# Can a fragment use another fragment in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

When I use a fragment in ANTLR4, can I use another fragment?

For example, I want to define a fragment `NUM_FRAGMENT` which uses  other fragments:

```
fragment DIGIT: [1-9];
fragment ZERO: [0];  
fragment NUM_FRAGMENT: ZERO | DIGIT | [0-9];
```

Is the example above allowed in ANTLR4?

Comment: Yes. You use "fragment" when you don't want the rule to return a token. Not only that, but fragment rules allow for the full power of a context-free grammar within a lexer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fragments can use other fragments.

In your example `fragment NUM_FRAGMENT: ZERO | DIGIT | [0-9];`, you can write `fragment NUM_FRAGMENT: ZERO | DIGIT;`.

Note that the naming of the rules is not entirely correct: `DIGIT` suggests it matches any digit (from 0 to 9). And `NUM_FRAGMENT` suggests it matches a number which should match one or more digits.

I'd write the rules like  this:

```
fragment NON_ZERO : [1-9];
fragment ZERO     : '0';  
fragment DIGIT    : ZERO | NON_ZERO;
fragment NUM      : DIGIT+;
```

Comment: You're wlecome @LeoPkm2-1